# I'm new in calculus and I couldn't solve this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, mathematical-physics

$|A - B| = \sqrt{2}|A + B|$ this is the equation and the question is, what's the magnitude of $B$?

Comment: Are $A,B$ real numbers or complex numbers ?

Comment: they're real numbers :)

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What does this have to do with mathematical physics?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that $A=0 \iff B=0$ is a trivial solution, then assume $A\neq 0$ and let $x=B/A$ then

$$|A - B| = \sqrt{2}|A + B|\iff |1 - x| = \sqrt{2}|1 + x|$$

hence we need to consider three cases

- $x<-1 \implies x-1=\sqrt 2(-1-x)$
- $-1\le x<1 \implies 1-x=\sqrt 2(-1-x)$
- $x\ge 1 \implies 1-x=\sqrt 2(1+x)$